# having trouble connecting to Shopify API php

Tags: php, api, shopify

My PHP skills consist of your basic Loops and Functions. I'm more of a HTML, CSS and Javascript guy.

Connecting with an API using PHP (or just connecting to an API in general) is not something I've done before.

I'm trying to connect to the Shopify API. Their documentation on PHP is sorely insufficient. I only got [this](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/php-api-faq) from their documentation:

```
<?php
  //Modify these
  $API_KEY = 'your-token-here';
  $SECRET = 'your-secret-here';
  $TOKEN = 'your-secret-here';
  $STORE_URL = 'yourestore.myshopify.com';
  $PRODUCT_ID = 'product-id-here';

  $url = 'https://' . $API_KEY . ':' . md5($SECRET . $TOKEN) . '@' . $STORE_URL . '/admin/products/' . $PRODUCT_ID . '.xml';

  $session = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1); 
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml', 'Content -Type: application/xml'));
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  if(ereg("^(https)",$url)) curl_setopt($session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

  $response = curl_exec($session);
  curl_close($session);

  $product_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response); 

  echo $product_xml->title;
  echo $product_xml->variants->variant->{'inventory-quantity'};
?>
```

I'm having trouble with the first part. `$API_KEY`, `$SECRET` and `$TOKEN` I know, but `$STORE_URL` and `$PRODUCT_ID` are giving me trouble.
Although it seems logical the `$STORE_URL` should be the url of the store I'm creating the app (plugin) for, because the API should know where to get information from. But I'm hesitant about filling it in because the app is supposed to be public. I'm my mind the URL should be variable to the url of the shop that downloads the app. I can't find any answer to this.
As for `$PRODUCT_ID`, I don't even know what that could be. I'm not given any product id alongside the API key. Products in the shopify store each have their own ID, but to me it seems the API shouldn't bind itself to one product.

I'm not completely a-technical, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this one. Especially because of lack of documentation.

[Shopify does provide some libraries](http://docs.shopify.com/api/libraries/php), but again, the documentation is not sufficient for someone like me.

Can somebody shine a light for me?

Comment: Why don't you simple use `http://www.shopify.com/contact` as you think that documentation isn't good enough?

Comment: This code is for the header of a product page, if I'm reading it correctly. So each page will have a different product_id

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I'm already in contact with them. And although their support is great, I'm currently being transferred from one person to the other.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall So... I shouldn't use this code if I simply want to connect to the Shopify API?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can create API keys through your shop admin:

1. From your shop admin, go to the Apps page.
2. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. At the bottom you should see the following:
3. Click private API key link.
4. If this is your first time, click Generate new Private App
5. Add a Title and click Save.
6. A new API key will be generated for you. It should look similar to this

More information and screenshoats at: [Shopify - API key](http://docs.shopify.com/support/configuration/apps/where-do-i-find-my-api-key)

`STORE_URL` is either `yourestore.myshopify.com` or `http://yourestore.myshopify.com` - you need to check both (I think it's the second one)

`PRODUCT_ID` is id of product you want to get data:

> product_id: The unique numeric identifier for the product.

so you should probably check your product id from your shop admin panel. If you cannot / don't know how to do that, you can first get list of products using `/admin/products.json` in your url.

One more thing - are you sure you can also get data in XML format? At `http://docs.shopify.com/api/product` as examples there are only urls in JSON

http://docs.shopify.com/api/product

Comment: Already did that. In my post I say I'm not having trouble with filling in the API key and Token, because I got provided with those by following the steps you also described here. My problem is with the `shop_url` and `product_id`.

Comment: Please look at edited question. First, you should probably display your `$url` variable and simple run this url in browser to make sure url is valid and you get any data.

Comment: Hmm.. the gist of the app is to let the user manipulate the price of the products in a collection to their choice. I'm getting the feeling this sample code Shopify provided is not usable in my situation.

Comment: And what's the problem with that? You can use `http://docs.shopify.com/api/product#update` to update your product